# .htaccess won't rewrite correctly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm having some issues with my .htaccess file, stored at the root level of my website.

I want to rewrite the following

1. mysite.com executes mysite.com/index.php?lang=en but rewrites the URL to mysite.com/en/
2. mysite.com/en (without the trailing slash) does the same as above
3. mysite.com/en/blog/page executes mysite.com/blog/page?lang=en

In a nutshell, add the language to the URL, opening index.php with either .com, .com/en or .com/en/, and strip the file extension

Here is the complete file for reference:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect to domain without www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Same for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Stop hotlinking.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^/]+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %1#%{HTTP_HOST} !^(.+)#\1$
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$ - [NC,F,L]

# Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes

# Request language from URL
# empty url -> redirect to en/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=(en|de)
RewriteRule ^$ en/ [R=301,L]

# now all urls have en/ de/ -> parse them
RewriteRule ^(en|de)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1&%{query_STRING} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

For full disclosure, it has all been taken from a variety of Google results, and I appreciate it could perhaps be done better.

As it stands, mysite.com gives me

> The requested URL /home/towrafvk/public_html/en/.php was not found on this server.

mysite.com/en gives me

> The requested URL /en.php was not found on this server.

mysite.com/en/ AND mysite.com/en/blog/page both work as intended

I know the issue is in the third-to-last and second-to-last Rewrite rules. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect to domain http(s) without www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{HTTPS}s ^www\.([^#]+)#(?:off|on(s)) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

# Stop hotlinking.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^/]+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %1#%{HTTP_HOST} !^(.+)#\1$
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$ - [NC,F,L]

# Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes

# Request language from URL
# empty url -> redirect to en/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=(en|de)
RewriteRule ^$ en/ [R=301,L]

# now all urls have en/ de/ -> parse them
RewriteRule ^(en|de)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

# Use .php file only if not exist without and exist with .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```